# Swift Package Manager don't allow to build package which contains `import AppKit`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've tried add `Kingfisher` via SPM for project targeted only on iOS, and got next error message `AppKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator`.

How to tell XCode that I do not want build for Mac?

XCode 11.6
Swift 5.1
MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Full error message: AppKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator. Consider using `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` to conditionally import this framework when building for Mac Catalyst.

Comment: Instead of creating an iOS project, you can select the macOS tab when creating a new project in Xcode to select creating a Cocoa Application

Comment: Issue was fixed in latest versions.